# hibernate returning a "No query defined for that name" error when using "jar-file" property

Tags: hibernate

I have my war application which uses entities defined in multiple jar files. In my `persistence.xml` I have defined one `jar-file` tag for each one of those jars, but the entities contained in those jars are not loaded when the application starts. If I specify each class using the "class" tag everything works fine.

I'm sure that the relative path defined for those jars is correct, because if I change it I get the error:
*"HHH10000002: File or directory named by URL [vfs:...] could not be found"*

This is my `persistence.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="custom-persistence-unit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/customdatasource</jta-data-source>
        <jar-file>lib/firstJar.jar</jar-file>
        <jar-file>lib/secondJar.jar</jar-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transactionJtaPlatform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="legacy-jpa"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Am I missing something? The log does not contain any error or warning, it looks like the entities are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your `persistence.xml` in the following way:

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.2"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

 ...
</persistence>
```

As it's stated in the *8.2.1.6.3 Jar Files* section of the JPA 2.2 specification:

> One or more JAR files may be specified using the `jar-file` elements instead of, or in addition to the mapping files specified in the `mapping-file` elements. If specified, these JAR files will be searched for managed persistence classes, and any mapping metadata annotations found on them will be processed, or they will be mapped using the mapping annotation defaults defined by this specification. Such JAR files are specified relative to the directory or jar file that *contains*[91] the root of the persistence unit.[92]
>
> [91] *This semantics applies to `persistence.xml` files written to the `persistence_2_0.xsd` or later schema. Due to ambiguity in the Java Persistence 1.0 specification, provider-specific interpretation of the relative references used by this element may apply to earlier
> versions.*
>
> [92] Persistence providers are encouraged to support this syntax for use in Java SE environments

Comment: Hi Stern, tried but it did not work

Comment: What application server do you use? It's really difficult to say something more without a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Wildfly 21 with hibernate 5.5.3.Final... I'll see if I can create a github project to reproduce the issue